# Does jqgrid frozen column work with treegrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, frozen-columns

I am trying to use the new frozen column feature with a treegrid and it doesn't seem to work.   Is this supported in jqgrid ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per the documentation mention [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afrozencolumns#limitations) the frozen columns are not supported when treegrid is enabled.

Comment: the URL to the documentation should be better [the following](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns#limitations)

Comment: changed the url, @Oleg: Thanks